# How not to display this small useless widget when my discord bot reffers to reddit

Tags: python, discord, bots

How not to display this small useless widget when my discord bot refers to reddit:

[image: here it is]

Is it possible to make this small widget not displayed?

Here is my code:

```
    @client.command()
async def reddit(ctx, arg, arg2 = None):
    if not arg2:
        await ctx.send('https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=' + str(arg))
        await ctx.send('`^ Searching for` ' + str(arg) + '`... ^`')
    if arg2:
        await ctx.send('https://www.reddit.com/' + str(arg2) + '/search?q=' + str(arg) + '&restrict_sr=1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the link in `< >`

```py
await ctx.send('<https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=' + str(arg) + ">")
```

It's a Discord feature, not just specific to writing bots.